# Importing data to mysql RDS with python multiprocessor - RDS

Tags: python, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, rds

I have some very peculiar behavior happening when running a data importer using multiprocessor in python.  I believe that this is a database issue, but I am not sure how to track it down.  Below is a description of the process I am doing:

1)  Multiprocessor file that runs XX number of processors doing parts two and three

2)  Queue processor that iterates through an sqs queue pulling a company id.  This id is used to pull a json string stored in mysql.  This json string is loaded as a json object and sent to a parsing file that normalizes the data so that it can be imported into mysql as normalized data.

3)  Company parser/importer reads through json object and creates inserts into a mysql database, normalizing the data.  These are batch inserted into RDS in batches of XXX size to mitigate IOPS issues.

This code is run from a c4.Large instance and works.  When it is started, it works fast (~30,000 inserts per min) without maxing out IOPS, CPU, or other resources on either the RDS or ec2 instance.  Then, after a certain amount of time (5-30min), the RDS server's CPU drops to ~20% and has a weird heartbeat type of rhythm.  I have tried launching additional ec2 instances to speed up this process and the import speed remains unchanged and slow (~2000 inserts per min), so I believe the bottleneck is with the RDS instance.  I tried changing the RDS instance's size from medium to large with no change.  I also tried changing the RDS instance's IOPS to provisioned SSD with 10k.  This also did not fix the problem

As far as I can tell, there is some sort of throttling or limitation by the RDS server.  But, I don't know where else to look.  There are no red flags about what is being limited.

**Can you please provide other potential reasons for why this type of behavior would be happening?  I don't know what else to test.**

Current setup is 500gb t2.medium RDS instance with ~200 Write IOPS, CPU at ~20%, Read IOPS < 20, Queue < 1, stable 12 db connections(this is not connecting and then disconnecting), and plenty of free memory.

Comment: t2.medium? Check your CPU credit balance graph in the cloudwatch monitoring for the RDS instance.  CPU @ 20% with a periodic "heartbeat" type of rhythm strongly suggests you're depleting it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - That is exactly what the problem was.  I have never heard of CPU credit...  I found this article, but would appreciate any explanation in layman's terms as well as advice for fixing it and avoiding the problem.  A c4.Large instance?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upping my instance type to a m3.Large instance without limited CPU credits.  Everything works well now.